# Can't get record from controller to visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, soql, lookup, pdf

Visualforce page

```
 <apex:variable value="{!record.Reservation__c}" var="Client">


        <p align="left" >

            full {!Client.Name} <br/>
            address{!Client.Contact__r.AddressOne__c}<br/>
            address {!Client.Contact__r.City__c}<br/>

            address {!Client.Contact__r.StateOrProvince__c}<br/>
            address {!Client.Contact__r.PostalCode__c}<br/>

            <br/>
            Dear firstname:
        </p></apex:variable>
```

Controller

```
    public List<Reservation__c > getRecords(Id reservationId) {
    List<Reservation__c > records = [Select Client_Name__c , Reservation_ID__c ,  Number_of_Guests__c, Arrival_Date__c ,Departure_Date__c, Total_Price__c, 
                                     Contact__r.Name, Contact__r.AddressOne__c, Contact__r.City__c, Contact__r.StateOrProvince__c, Contact__r.PostalCode__c 
                                //        ,(Select AddressOne__c , City__c, StateOrProvince__c     From Contact__r )
                               //        (Select Name, Unit_Price__c From Purchase_Lookup__r ORDER BY Name ASC)
                                     From Reservation__c 

                                     WHERE Id =: reservationId                                        
                                     ];

    return records;
}
```

I'm trying to create a pdf invoice from reservation.
But I'm keep getting "Unknown property 'GenerateInvoiceController.record'"
Error message.
Can you guys tell me what went wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is "record" supposed to be? What is "record.Reservation__c" supposed to be? Does the page have a `standardController` attribute? How is `getRecords` called? How are these records related? There's simply too many unanswered questions here to help you. Please **[edit]** your question to include more details about this code. It's obvious from the error that there's no controller/extension variable/method named `record/getRecord`, but aside from that, there's simply not enough information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VF code is actually using a variable called {!record}

```
<apex:variable value="{**!record**.Reservation__c}" var="Client">
```

Bu your class has no record variable. It actually has a method called getRecords()